# MPMoviePlayerController, slow/crashes on iPod Touch

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, ipod-touch

I am building an application with iPhone SDK 3.1.3.

All I am trying to do is play a 2 Minute(11MB Filesize video) and loop it.

I have code that works find on the simulator, iPhone 3G & iPhone 3GS, but not on an iPod TOuch 8GB.

When I run the code on the iPod Touch, it gets to the line:
movPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: videoURL];

It will then sit there for a while before the OS kills the process.

Any ideas?

Zac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue.  Something about the actual video encoding was causing a problem that only happened on the iPod touch;  the video would play fine on a iPhone 3G, iPhone 3GS and the simulator.

Perhaps, try re-encoding the video.

Comment: Would you be able to share what encoding works on the ipod touch?